# Create list per 4 records

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create multi-list of records with 4 records per list without knowing how many records there are. However, I cannot figure out how to handle the math. I manually typed in $n == 5 || $n == 9 etc knowing it is stipud and cannot exactly solve the problem. Can anyone help me how to handle that. Also, the lists underneath works well only if the total number of records cannot be evenly divided by 4. If it can, it will create a blank list at the end.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field` = $whatever";
if ($result = $con->query($query)){
$n = 1
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
$total_lists = round($row_cnt / 4, 0);
$current_list = 1;
echo "<ul>List $current_list of $total_lists";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<li>$row['something']</li>";
        if ($n == 5 || $n == 9 || $n == 13 || $n == 17 || $n == 21 || $n ==25 || $n ==29 || $n == 33 || $n == 37 || $n == 41 || $n == 45 || $n == 49 || $n == 53 || $n == 57 || $n == 61 || $n == 65 || $n == 69 || $n == 73 || $n == 77){
        echo "</ul>";
        $current_list = $current_list + 1;
        echo "<ul>List $current_list of $total_lists";
        }
    $n = $n + 1;
    }
echo "</ul>";
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help. :)

SOLVED:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field` = $whatever";
if ($result = $con->query($query)){
$n = 0
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
$total_lists = ceil($row_cnt / 4);
$current_list = 1;
echo "<ul>List $current_list of $total_lists";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $n++;
    echo "<li>$row['something']</li>";
        if ($row_cnt > 4) {
    if ($n % 4 === 0) {
    echo "</ul>";
    $current_list = $current_list + 1;
    echo "<ul>List $current_list of $total_lists";
        }
        }
    }
echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: Ever heard of modulus operator: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php?

Comment: alternatively, you can chunk (`array_chunk()`) your array results by four's, then they should be grouped by four and then just loop them accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually not too far off track from what you might want to be doing, you just need to use one additional tool to accomplish it: the `%` or modulus operator.

The modulus operator will return the remainder of division problem:

```
$x = 5 % 2; // 1
```

Looking at your logic, your action needs to be taken when your incrementer (`$n`) minus 1 divided by 4 would have a remainder of 0:

```
if (($n - 1) % 4 === 0)
{
    //your <ul> insertion could go here.
}
```

Here's a link to the PHP manual page discussing mathematical operators:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: Thank you so much! First time come across the modulus operator and it works well in my situation!! :)

Comment: By the way, I still have the last page being blank if the total number of records can be evenly divided by 4. I think I can handle that of course in another stupid unefficient way :p

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen You have the `$current_list` variable (which tracks your current list) and you previously calculated the total number of lists to output (`$total_lists`). You could check if these two numbers equal each other. If they do, you can `break;` out of your loop prior to opening the final, empty list: http://us2.php.net/break

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't think that's the case. I think I have a problem with rounding $total_lists.

Comment: Check out the PHP function `ceil()`. This will always round a float to the next highest integer. If you have 5 entries divide that by 4 to get your list count, you will only have 1 (1.25 rounds to 1). `ceil` will round that up to two. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use a simple `array_chunk()` on your db results. Provide the proper grouping (in this case by four's) to it and them loop them thru foreach. Consider this example:

```
// dummy data (values from db)
$values_from_db = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'something' => 'list1'),
    array('id' => 2, 'something' => 'list2'),
    array('id' => 3, 'something' => 'list3'),
    array('id' => 4, 'something' => 'list4'),
    array('id' => 5, 'something' => 'list5'),
    array('id' => 6, 'something' => 'list6'),
    array('id' => 7, 'something' => 'list7'),
    array('id' => 8, 'something' => 'list8'),
    array('id' => 9, 'something' => 'list9'),
);

$values_from_db = array_chunk($values_from_db, 4); // group them by four's

?>

<?php foreach($values_from_db as $key => $value): ?>
    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <?php foreach($value as $index => $element): ?>
        <li><?php echo $element['id'].'.'.$element['something']; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```